# Is that form of Cesàro's theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

First, for sequences, we know that : "If a sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ converges to $l\in \mathbb{R}$, then the sequence $(b_n)_{n \ge 1}$ defined by : $b_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ converges to $l$."

This theorem is also true when $l=\pm \infty$.

Now, for the series we have this statement : "If the series $(\sum a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $S=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} S_n=\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\sum \limits_ {k=1}^{n}a_k$, then the sequence $(b_n)_{n \ge 1}$ $b_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}S_k$ converges to $S$."

Like sequences the reciprocal is false (the Grandi's series) but I was wondering if we can affirm that :"If the series $(\sum a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ diverges to $\pm \infty$, then the sequence $(b_n)_{n \ge 1}$ $b_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}S_k$ also diverges." (It seems true according to wiki)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to Cesaro's theorem holding for $a_n\rightarrow\infty$ in the original form, after relabeling. Suppose $S_n$ diverges to $+\infty$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N(\epsilon)=N>0$ such that $S_n>\epsilon$ for all $n> N$. Then for $n>N$:

$$b_n=\frac{1}{n}(S_1+\cdots +S_N)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^nS_k\geq \frac{1}{n}(S_1+\cdots +S_N)+\epsilon\frac{(n-N)}{n}\geq \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=\infty$. A similar argument follows for the $-\infty$ case.

Comment: Ok thanks, it is even easier that in the case where the series converges. Now, is it possible to find a sequence $(b_n)_{n\ge 1}$ which diverges and a series $(\sum a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ which converges ?

Comment: @Maman: No. Again this is exactly the Cesaro theorem. If $S_n$ (forget it's even a sum!) converges, then $b_n$ converges as well. Only the following holds: if $b_n$ converges then $S_n$ might not converge as is exhibited by say Grandi's series.

Comment: Ok I see but in that case, does the reciprocal work ?

Comment: @Maman: What do you mean by reciprocal?

Comment: For sequences : we can a find $(b_n)$ which converges for $(a_n)$ which admits no limit. Same for $\infty$.
Now I was wondering If we can find this type of exemple for series.

Comment: @Maman: Take $S_n$ to be the Grandi series : $S_n=1-1+1-1+\cdots$.

Comment: It's ok I get it ! Thank you !